# Display Chrome for Windows security zone for page

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-security

Is it possible to determine in Chrome what security zone it has decided to put a page into in the same way Internet Explorer 11 displays the zone for the current page when you select properties from the context menu for the page?

Comment: What do you mean by "security zone"? are you talking about trusted sites? Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @music2myear If you don't know what a security zone is, perhaps you can't answer. (PS A trusted site is a site that is in the trusted security zone, but it is only one of four possible zones. Chrome uses the IE Trusted Sites list to determine a site belongs in that zone, but does not match IE in determining what belongs to the Local Intranet zone.)

Comment: I do know what security zones are, and a site's assignment to one or another is based on various, generally known, criteria, including being directly added to that zone. Your question lacks a lot of context and when dealing with bare and one-liner questions like this I've learned it is best not to assume I'm thinking the same thing OP is, which is why I asked you to clarify your question. It is best that you add this and any other clarification to the body of the question itself so that the question becomes better and more clear.

Comment: Now that we know what you're talking about when you say "security zone", we still need more information. How were you hoping this information would be displayed? Were you hoping for a plugin or for some flag in Chrome itself that allowed this information to be displayed? What has your own research shown? What have you tried? Use the EDIT button to add any and all clarifying and relevant information to the body of the question itself to make it better and more clear and complete.

Comment: @music2myear Added more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Chrome has a concept of Zones. Chrome does read one or more of the zone lists for use in chrome policies/features. An example is why I went looking for the same question.

> In Windows only, if the command-line switch --auth-server-whitelist is not present, the permitted list consists of those servers in the Local Machine or Local Intranet security zone...

I am unable to find a way in Chrome to determine if the current website has indeed been whitelisted by Chrome other then by its behaviour, but again i dont believe chrome would consider this site as Intranet, as much as it would consider it auth-server-whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

Now that new Edge (Edgium) is based on Chromium, Microsoft has had to make clearer the interaction between zones and Chromium, which I believe applies to Chrome as well.

This [blog article](https://textslashplain.com/2020/01/30/security-zones-in-edge/) explains it clearly.

In summary, Chromium uses Security Zones for File Downloads and automatic Windows Integrated Authentication. An explicit site list policy for Authentication will override using Zones for WIA. New Edge will also use Zones for tabs that are in IE Mode, as they are actually running in IE 11.

Unfortunately New Edge has no way to display the zone for a particular page like IE 11.